databricks mflow model deployment and serving: Invalid input. setting an array element with a sequence. requested array has an inhomogeneous shape
Sample input/output
    # input_data = [
    #     np.array([229, 229, 229, 1501, 1501, 1501], dtype=np.int32),
    #     np.array([61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61], dtype=np.int32),
    #     np.array([
    #         [31.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
    #         [32.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
    #         [33.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
    #         [33.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
    #         [34.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
    #         [35.0, 118.61144, 89.0]
    #     ], dtype=np.float32)
    # ]

    # output_data = np.array([[2.331907],
    #        [2.328985],
    #        [2.3260572],
    #        [2.4161298],
    #        [2.413204],
    #        [2.410278]], dtype=np.float32)


I've successfully registered and served my keras model 'model.h5' on my azure databricks using the following code snippet.
    model_path = '/Workspace/Shared/PP_V2/models/model.h5'

    input_schema = Schema(
        [
            TensorSpec(np.dtype(np.int32), (-1,), "field1"),  # Variable batch size
            TensorSpec(np.dtype(np.int32), (-1,), "field2"),  # Variable batch size
            TensorSpec(np.dtype(np.float32), (-1, 3), "field3"),  # Variable batch size
        ]
    )

    output_schema = Schema(
        [
            TensorSpec(np.dtype(np.float32), (-1, 1), "output")  # Variable batch size
        ]
    )

    signature = ModelSignature(inputs=input_schema, outputs=output_schema)

    with mlflow.start_run() as run:
        model = load_model(model_path)
        log_model(
            model,
            artifact_path="keras-model",
            signature=signature,
            registered_model_name="model"
        )

I've got the following endpoint which should give me appropriate prediction as per the input
https://adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.azuredatabricks.net/serving-endpoints/model/invocations
when I send the post request to this endpoint with following json body
{
    "inputs": [
    [229, 229, 229, 1501, 1501, 1501],
    [61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61],
    [
        [31.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
        [32.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
        [33.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
        [33.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
        [34.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
        [35.0, 118.61144, 89.0]
    ]
]
}

I get the following response on the postman
{
    "error_code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Invalid input. setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (3, 6) + inhomogeneous part."
}

whereas this code snippet works perfectly fine and gives the desired output against the given input
    input_data = [
        np.array([229, 229, 229, 1501, 1501, 1501], dtype=np.int32),
        np.array([61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61], dtype=np.int32),
        np.array([
            [31.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
            [32.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
            [33.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
            [33.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
            [34.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
            [35.0, 118.61144, 89.0]
        ], dtype=np.float32)
    ]

    model_path = 'models/model.h5'
    final_model = keras.saving.load_model(model_path)

    predicted = final_model.predict(input_data)

    predicted

    np.array([[2.331907],
             [2.328985],
             [2.3260572],
             [2.4161298],
             [2.413204],
             [2.410278]], dtype=np.float32)

I've been able to reproduce this error outside this scenario but I am unable to come up with solution for this in this scenario. Following code snippet produces the error mentioned above
    data = [
        [229, 229, 229, 1501, 1501, 1501],
        [61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61],
        [
            [31.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
            [32.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
            [33.0, 118.61144, 280.0],
            [33.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
            [34.0, 118.61144, 89.0],
            [35.0, 118.61144, 89.0]
        ]
    ]

    np.asarray(data, dtype='float32')
 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (3, 6) + inhomogeneous part.
